# Unknown Command for Variable

Tags: amsmath, variable

I have been unable to identify the command for this specific volume variable, V. The closest commands I identified were `\vee` and `\wedge` but they do not possess the curvature found in this format. Any help would be appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that those formula was make with LaTeX? I don't think so.

Comment: The V letter looks ugly, sorry

Comment: @Sigur: If LaTeX etc, than with really bad kernings etc. ;-)

Comment: May be is simply a  italic V  (english)  or  nu (greek)  of some bizarre font.